# Как перенести коммиты из одного репозитория в другой?

Tags: git

Есть 2 репозитория, в одном изначально работа велась, другой создан для другого разработчика. Боль в том, что второй репозиторий был скопирован и инициализрован снова.

Разраб сделал изменения и вопрос как теперь перетащить их свой основной репозиторий? Работа в котором тоже велась.

Как быть? И что делать теперь?)

В данный момент коммиты вроде как перетащил с помощью remote [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по факту изменений никаких нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: @Эникейщик обновил вопрос) Может новая инфа даст больше инфы

Comment: Ваш форк идёт впереди и никак не связан с основной (для этого человека) веткой проекта. Пускай делает мерж. Эникейщик дал ссылку.

Comment: @test123 окей, а как быть с коммитами которые у меня в списке висят, коммиты из второго репа. И почему реально нет никаких изменений в файлах?

Comment: Вы не понимаете основ... Они у вас есть. Для того чтобы теперь это отразилось на файликах, надо создать новый коммит, и смержить в него чужие изменения и ваши наработки. (коммиты - это точки, своеобразные дампы файловой системы, мерж - это операция объединения состояния одной точки с состоянием второй точки. В процессе слияния могут быть конфликты, а может их и не быть, поэтому проводить мерж автоматически никто не будет. Вам самому надо это сделать.)

Comment: Рекомендую почитать про использование гита, на примере вашей UI оболочки над ним. Если хотите "прыгнуть" в одну из точек дампа файловой системы - ткните дважды на любую точку коммита, ваш UI сам подготовит и отобразит все файлики в каталоге. Но, прыгая из точки в точку - вы не сольёте два коммита. Для мержа надо почитать как выполнять эту операцию (скорее всего, в меню есть пункты, действия, или нечто подобное, где можно выбрать "слияние" или "merge").

Comment: @test123 спасибо! Сделал в принципе) Слияние делал через консоль

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так как хранилища имеют разную историю (второе хранилище, как я понял, было создано в виде коммита, содержащего файлы/каталоги первого хранилища на определённый момент времени), то наиболее безболезненный путь переноса изменений из второго хранилища в первое — воспользоваться связкой команд `format-patch` + `am`.

во втором хранилище надо сформировать файлы с патчами для каждого коммита, начиная с самого первого (он как раз **не** будет включен):

```
$ git format-patch хэш-первого-коммита
```

в текущем каталоге будут сформированы файлы вида:

```
0001-сообщение-коммита-следующего-за-указанным.patch
0002-сообщение-следующего-за-ним-коммита.patch
...
```

эти патчи надо командой `am` применить в первом хранилище:

```
$ git am /путь/к/каталогу/*.patch
```

---

в процессе применения могут, конечно, возникнуть конфликты. программа *git* подскажет, как действовать (устранить конфликт и продолжить, либо пропустить патч, либо прервать всю процедуру и вернуться к прежнему состоянию):

```
Applying: сообщение коммита, который вызвал сбой
error: описание причины ошибки
Patch failed at название файла с этим патчем
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```