# Как создать патч в GIT?

Tags: git

Как создать патч с текущей ветки(нужно перенести коммиты) и применить его  в новой?

Comment: Вам нужно перенести текущие изменения или прошлые?

Comment: я изменил данные на ветке в мастер, а нужно было в девелоп. Теперь хочу перенести изменения  создав ветку в  девелоп.

Comment: А до этого две ветки отличались друг от друга?

Comment: у меня была ветка мастер,когда сделал клон проекта, затем создал свою, сделал изменения, а оказалось нужно сделать было эту же ветку только с девелоп, теперь нужно  создать  такую же ветку на девелоп и закинуть изменения.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под девелоп? По сути так называют новую ветку, но в вашем контексте - это не так, кажется.

Comment: да, это другая ветка.

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чем проблема develop к master приравнять

Comment: фактически ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825948/178576

Comment: не не нужно приравнивать.Вам что тяжело сказать как патч сделать правильно?Если не хотите помочь, то прошу не задавать глупых вопросов. Отдельное спасибо  alexander barakin за подсказку.Попробую разобраться.